# IE 11 installed but still running IE8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I installed Internet Explorer 11 and I am still running IE8. I would like to uninstall IE8 or at least make IE11 the default one. I have been having issues previously to install it using Windows Update even if I had the Windows Update set to automatically install updates. Any idea why I still have IE8 running instead of IE11?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have both IE8 and IE11 installed on Windows 7, so it sounds to me like your IE11 install failed (or hasn't happened). Either that or your Windows is massively corrupted and you should consider a reinstall.

Install IE11 again, perhaps by using the full/offline installer offered by Microsoft:

- [Download Internet Explorer 11 (Offline installer)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/internet-explorer/ie-11-worldwide-languages)

Comment: Thank you Techie007 but the offline installer did not work. The strange thing is that it says that IE11 did not finish installing and put a troubleshooting link in my desktop. followed the link and went through each individual required update for IE installation. turned out that all of the PreRequisite updates are already installed in my computer. Even Window update tries to install IE11 but each time gets an error.

Answer (score 0):

You may have downloaded ie11, but it is not "ON". A place to check:

Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features

[image: pandf]

Be sure internet explorer 11 is present and the box is checked.

[image: checked]

If IE11 is not available in that menu, it did not get installed. Also, IE11 is usually auto downloaded in the windows update. It could be that it is hidden from available updates.

Comment: Thanks Carl B, but that is exactly what I am talking about. Unfortunately I am new to superuser and cannot upload picture. But this is exactly what I have right now when I go to Windows Features. I see IE11 and it is checked. What does not make sense is that when I run IE, it's version 8 that I am getting. It would have made sense if I had IE8 in Windows Features.

Comment: @Reogo - do you have hidden updates? Go to updates and click restore hidden updates and see if IE11 is among them. If so, I will edit my answer. Also, where do you launch the browser? From a desktop shortcut?

Comment: I have no hidden update. And I tried both to launch it using the desktop shortcut and using the installation directory. And it's the same result.

Comment: @Reogo: Did you get this resolve?  I am having the exact symptoms as you had described!!!